# Pthread doesn't work properly. c programming

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to implement a mutex lock example code, but it doesn't work as well as the theory of mutex lock.
I create 10 threads for my program, 9 threads are reading an array and one thread change the array. In the theory of lock, if I lock the array before changing it then other threads can not read it.
but my program runs differently. please check the code below and help me to understand where to call pthread mutex lock functions:

```
// C program to generate random numbers
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 10

pthread_mutex_t lock;
int array[1000] = {0};
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

int change_array(int *array)
{
    int arrayhelper[1000] = {0};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        arrayhelper[i] = i;
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        array[i] = 0;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        array[i] = arrayhelper[i];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);    
    

    return 1;
}

void *read_array(){
    while(1)
        if (array[10] == 0)
            printf("%d failed to lock!\n", array[10]);
}

void *write_array(){
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        change_array(array);
    }
}

int main (){
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        array[i] = i;

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, *write_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, *read_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, *read_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[3], NULL, *read_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[4], NULL, *read_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[5], NULL, *read_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[6], NULL, *read_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[7], NULL, *read_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[8], NULL, *read_array, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[9], NULL, *read_array, NULL);

    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[2], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[3], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[4], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[5], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[6], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[7], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[8], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[9], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 1;
}
```

Theoretically, when you run this code, the read_array function should not print anything but in a moment array elements will be 0 and other threads achieve that.

Comment: What books did you read about Pthreads? I recommend *Programming with Pthreads* ISBN 0-201-63392-2. Don't forget to call `fflush`

Comment: "In the theory of lock, if I lock the array before changing it then other threads can not read it." That theory is wrong. Locking a mutex in one thread will not stop the other threads. Everyone needs to lock the mutex.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation. I will check them and will ask you more if needed. @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Do you mean I should use lock functions in other threads?
@n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: Here's the correct theory of mutexes. Mutexes prevent *blocks of code* from running simultaneously. That's all they do. They do not magically lock data. They lock pieces of code. If you want to prevent two pieces of code from running simultaneously, you lock the same mutex at the beginning of both pieces, and unlock it at the end of both pieces. The first one to reach the lock will lock it. The second one will reach the lock and wait until it is unlocked. The end.

Comment: That's right, my code works well with your help, thanks.
I was thought when I use the lock, all shared memory will be locked and none of the other threads can achieve them. now I know that I need to use the lock in every thread. @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.